# Angular validation: if dynamically add required attribute validation will break

Tags: angularjs

Trying to dynamically add validation to input file if I choose first option from select. But if I add `required` attribute, it still `ng-valid` in class. If I load file to input file, it still `ng-empty`.
What's wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/pjyCULes60jWf7yqNsyB?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The form validation in AngularJS depends on the `ngModel` attribute, which doesn't work with `input type=file`.

To solve this, either use [ngFileUpload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) which helps you solve other problems you'll encounter with file upload in Angular as well, or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383446/how-to-validate-form-with-inputtype-file-in-angularjs) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795404/validation-doesnt-work-for-file-input-with-required-attribute-angularjs) answer.

Comment: Could you advice me something to solve this problem?

Comment: As you can see, I added directive that creates the new attribute. The problem is in adding attribute dynamically. If I choose proper option and input file will show with adding valid-file attribute, ng-classes will not change, it stay ng-valid.

Comment: Do you know how to get the length of the loaded file? Something like this: $scope.userInfo.loadedFile.length() don't work :(

Comment: And I can't use ngFileUpload because I use another bootstrap plugin to stylize the input file.

Comment: I solved my problem. I used ng-if and I don't need dynamically add the attributes. Just add them in input tag.